# eksctl command to create eks cluster under a certain VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

In my AWS account, I have a VPC that I want to create an EKS cluster under. How do I modify this command to create the cluster under said VPC?

```
eksctl create cluster \
--name app-api \
--version 1.29 \
--region us-east-1 \
--nodegroup-name app-api-worker-group \
--node-type t2.micro \
--nodes 1
```

Comment: You can use `--vpc-private-subnets subnet-ExampleID1,subnet-ExampleID2`

Comment: Is there a way to use the vpc-id?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to specify VPC ID at the command line, eksctl will automatically determine the VPC ID when you specify the subnets (`--vpc-private-subnets`, `--vpc-public-subnets`) to use. Note that in this case you are to ensure the VPC fully met the EKS [network requirement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network_reqs.html). See [here](https://eksctl.io/usage/vpc-configuration/#use-existing-vpc-other-custom-configuration) for complete details.

Comment: where do I find the `--vpc-private-subnets` and `--vpc-public-subnets` of a VPC?

Comment: On the AWS console goto VPC, select the VPC you want to use and find the subnets at `Resource map`.

Comment: under `Resource Map`, it displays that subnets are 0.